# Modularization common closure principle with reflection

Tags: java, maven, java-8

Having this maven project structure

```
root pom
     ---> ModuleCore/pom.xml
     ---> ModuleA/pom.xml
     ---> ModuleB/pom.xml
     ---> ModuleC/pom.xml
     ---> ModuleD/pom.xml
```

Where Module `A, B, C and D` has dependency with Module `Core` and also let's say `ModuleA` has a dependency with `ModuleB` and `ModuleB` has a dependency with `ModuleC`.

With this dependecy distribution, we agree that:

If I modify

```
  ModuleCore
```

Have to version

```
  ModuleA/pom.xml
  ModuleB/pom.xml
  ModuleC/pom.xml
  ModuleD/pom.xml
```

If I update `ModuleD` nobody has to version.

And if I update `ModuleC`

Have to version

```
  ModuleA/pom.xml
  ModuleB/pom.xml
```

Ok after the whole explanation, what I want to achieve is that no module has dependencies between each other but only with `ModuleCore`

My first appoach has been create interfaces as contract to comunicate between modules and put that contract in the `moduleCore`, and then invoke the implementation by `reflection` looking in the `classpath` for implementation of that interfaces and invoking. But I dont feel well about reflection looks hacky,

Could somebody please give me some advices how to applym Common closure principle without move all code into ModuleCore and make a monolith?.

Example of code of my first approach using Reflection.

```
@Test
void dependencyWithModuleA() {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.modularization.ccp");
    Optional<Optional<?>> any = reflections.getSubTypesOf(MainA.class)
            .stream()
            .map(clazz -> {
                try {
                    MainA mainA = clazz.newInstance();
                    return Optional.of(mainA.main());
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return Optional.empty();
            }).findAny();
    if (any.isPresent() && any.get().isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(any.get().get());
    }

}
```

Important to clarify that the reflection invocation it will done in the startup of the service, and the instance reference it will be save using Singleton pattern for futures invocations  to avoid performance issues.

Please all of the criticism about this aproach it will be more than welcome.

Regards.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of these dependencies between modules? Normally, there's nothing wrong when a module depends on another. When the whole project is built, they will be synchronized and incompatible changes will be visible right away. If you use reflection, there is a high risk that some hidden stuff breaks at runtime, which is much more annoying than during the build.

Comment: Basically to deliver independent libraries as toolkit Mode.

Comment: Also for minor fix in modules

Answer (score 1):

From the tags on the question, it looks like this question is restricted to Java 8.  Working with that assumption...

Have a look at the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class which is built into the JDK.  You can declare the implementations of `MainA` in a `META-INF/package.MainA` file - in each of `ModuleA-D` jars.  Then to find those implementations:

```
ServiceLoader.load(MainA.class).iterator()
```

With Java 9 things change a little.  Now a JDK9 module can directly declare its services, but they can still be discovered via `ServiceLoader`, so this approach has a level of future proofing too.

Clearly there are quite a few more solutions to this outside the JDK as well, e.g. Spring has autowiring, or `ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(Class)`, Java EE has `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`, there's OSGi, etc...

Comment: Thanks I was considering SPI as well, not sure yet. The Spring approach it will require introduce Spring ecosystem in the application, at least for DI. I was looking for the less intrusive solution, but I will consider all your suggestions. Thanks